# Get root property of an object using recursion

Tags: javascript, oop, for-loop, recursion, data-structures

My algorithm works correctly when I apply fake objects to the function but on CodeWars it continues to fail. I'm very curious on what checks I'm missing in my code. I believe I have to use certain regular expressions but I'm very confused. Here's a link to the problem https://www.codewars.com/kata/get-root-property-name

```
function getRootProperty(object, val) {
var valueFound = false;
let output = '';
 for (var first in object) {
 var seachObject = object[first]
  function query(object, val, rootName) {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object).forEach((value) => {
      if (object[value] == val) {
        valueFound = true;
        output = rootName
        return
      } else {
        query(object[value], val, rootName)
      }
    })
}
  query(seachObject, val, first);
}

if (valueFound == false) {
   return null
} else {
   return output;
}

}
```

Comment: A link to the codewars problem description would be useful, i just see a bunch of code that is supposed to do something i don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily i only had to search new CodeWars problems and found it relatively fast: [Problem description](https://www.codewars.com/kata/get-root-property-name). Here is your issue: `[...] other root properties may also have 9 buried in it but you should always return the first`

Use `if (!valueFound) query(object[value], val, rootName)` for the first call (doesn't matter for the recursive calls).

The problem assumes an order in javascript properties which works in ecmascript8, partly in ecmascript6 and not at all in lower versions.

Comment: I added your recommendation to the 'else' statement by creating an 'else if' statement and that was passed all of their tests. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may also do as follows;

```js
function findRootProperty(o,x,p = this){
  return Object.keys(o)
               .reduce((r,k) => Array.isArray(o[k]) ? o[k].includes(x) ? r.concat(k)
                                                                       : r
                                                    : r.concat(findRootProperty(o[k],x,k)),[])
               .map(q => p === this ? q : p );
}

object = {
    "r1n": {
        "mkg": {
            "zma": [21, 45, 66, 111],
            "mii": {
                "ltf": [2, 5, 3, 9, 21]
             },
             "fv": [1, 3, 6, 9]
         },
         "rmk": {
             "amr": [50, 50, 100, 116, 150, 250]
         }
    },
    "fik": {
        "er": [592, 92, 32, 13],
        "gp": [12, 34, 116, 29]
    }
};

console.log(findRootProperty(object,116))
```